Как из существующей модели сделать базового пользователя
В models.py прописана бд с сущностью Account, как из этой сущности сделать базового пользователя для входа в аккаунт.
class Account(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    FML = models.TextField()
    login = models.TextField()
    phone = models.IntegerField()
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.login

Так же на эту сущность ссылается другая:
class Investor(models.Model):
    id_Account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    id_ViewClient = models.ForeignKey(ViewClient, on_delete= models.PROTECT)
    name = models.TextField()
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

Пробовал через setting писать что ээто базовый пользователь, но не получилось

Для того, чтобы ваша модель была базовой моделью пользователя желательно (не уверен, что обязательно), чтобы эта модель наследовалась от models.AbstractUser, а так же её нужно зарегистрировать в settings.py.

Модель AbstractUser по стандарту имеет следующие поля:

username
first_name
last_name
email
is_staff
is_active
date_joined
password
last_login
is_superuser
groups
user_permissions


А для того чтобы зарегистрировать модель нужно в файле settings.py в конце написать:
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'приложение_с_моделью.название_модели'

LOGIN_URL = 'ссылка_на_страницу_авторизации' #'/user/login' например

Может конечно для этого есть другие способы, но я использую этот.
